# How to politely respond when someone calls your name?

Tags: greetings, responses

I found the following example in Genesis 22:1:

> Some time later God tested Abraham and said to him, “Abraham!” “Here I am,” he answered.

Is "here I am" considered as a polite response when someone called your name? Are there any polite alternatives?

I am aware of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134343/what-are-some-polite-ways-to-respond-to-the-people-who-call-your-name-but-you-do); what I am asking here is a polite response when someone whom you know calls you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking English Lessons from Abraham is a new idea!

It's polite to say "Here I am". But it is not a common response.

You would have to understand the context in which someone is saying your name. Sometimes when someone calls your name it implies

> Abraham! <Where are you? I can't see you>

In which case you could come from the place in which you are hiding and say "Here I am!".

More often it means

> Abraham! <Look this way and pay attention to me>

In this case, it would be normal to respond:

> Yes  <I will pay attention to you>

or

> What? <do you want from me?>

Sometimes it means

> Abraham. <It's good to see you>

So you would respond with

> Hello.